# Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP, but I can't access php.ini

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, intl

I installed cakephp 3.x and made code out of it and it's working on my localhost..
But after I deploy my code to web hosting, i got error

> Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /home/elgayaca/public_html/config/bootstrap.php on line 38

I couldn't reach php.ini on webserver..

I already ask the webserver operator to enable the intl extention, but it is still not working..

what should I do? please help..

Comment: you need to ask your server provider to install intl extension on your hosting

Comment: Change hosting provider, find one which allow you to select php extensions and change php version from control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not intl extension in your php.

There are different ways to install it depends on your OS.
Here the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php)

Comment: She can't install extension on shared host.

Comment: Yes, you a right. I missed this. But I see no other option to handle it

Comment: @Salines Thank you for the answer, it's really the problem of the web hosting.. :(

Comment: @Dmytrechko thank you for the answer